# Proportion distribution of column values by date

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to get the proportion of each category in the data set by day, to be able to plot it eventually.

Sample (daily_usage):

```
       type  date        count
0      A     2016-03-01    70
1      A     2016-03-02    64
2      A     2016-03-03    38
3      A     2016-03-04    82
4      A     2016-03-05    37
...
412    G     2016-03-27   149
413    G     2016-03-28   382
414    G     2016-03-29   232
415    G     2016-03-30   312
416    G     2016-03-31   412
```

I plotted the mean and median by type just fine with the following code:

```
 daily_usage.groupby('type')['count'].agg(['median','mean']).plot(kind='bar')
```

But I wanted a similar plot with the **proportion** of the daily counts instead. However, for plotting it eventually, I don't need to show the date. It would be just to show the average/median daily proportion for each type.

The proportion interpretation I mean is, for example, for the first line: type A happened 70 times in March 1; considering all other events in March 1, there is a sum of 948 events. The proportion of type A in March 1 is 70/948. This would be computed for all rows. The final plot will have to show each type on the x-axis, and the average daily proportion on the y-axis

I tried getting the proportion in two ways.

First one:

```
daily_usage['ratio'] = (daily_usage / daily_usage.groupby('date').transform(sum))['count']
```

The denominator in this first try gives me this sample output, so it looks like it should be very easy to divide the original count column by this new daily count column:

```
           count
0    ...   948
1    ...   910
2    ...   588
3    ...   786
4    ...   530
5    ...  1043
```

Error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'
```

Second one:

```
daily_usage.div(day_total,axis='count')
```

where `day_total = daily_usage.groupby('date').agg({'count':'sum'}).reset_index()`

Error:

```
 TypeError: ufunc true_divide cannot use operands with types dtype('<M8[ns]') and dtype('<M8[ns]')
```

What's a better way to do this?

Comment: sooo does just removing the `x axis` and plot with the same first method enough for you ? because that can be done easily

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by removing the x-axis. Can you explain?  The proportion interpretation I mean is, for example, for the first line: type A happened 70 times in March 1; considering all other events in March 1, there is a sum of 948 events. The proportion of type A in March 1 is 70/948. This would be computed for all rows. The final plot will have to show each type on the x-axis, and the average daily proportion on the y-axis.

Comment: I am sure it is easy. I am just a big newbie in python. :/

Comment: alright, give me a second to create a sample dataframe and test it before answering (to make sure and stuff)

Comment: what is your output

Comment: it can be a new 'ratio' column of the value in the 'count' column by the sum of the counts on the same day.

Comment: I tried again the second method like this: `daily_usage.div(day_total,axis='count')`, where `day_total = daily_usage.groupby('date').transform(sum)['count'].reset_index()`. It almost works, but gives this error: `ZeroDivisionError: division by zero`. Apparently, it's finding dates that do not have any events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you just want to have your new column in your dataframe you can do the following:

```
df['ratio'] = (df.groupby(['type','date'])['count'].transform(sum) / df.groupby('date')['count'].transform(sum))
```

However, it has nearly been 20 mins now that I'm trying to figure out what you're trying to plot exactly and since I still didn't really get your intention I ask from you to leave a **detailed** comment in case you need help plotting and precise what you want to plot and how ( one plot for the daily usage of each day or some other form ).

PS:

in my code `df` refers to your `daily_usage` dataframe.

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: You did it!! Thank so much! I got the plot already. I just replaced the new 'ratio' column instead of the 'count' column in the original code.

Comment: oh that was it ? i thought there's still something to do :p well happy i could help then @Helk